# How to get iso date from an arquero datetime?

Tags: javascript, arquero

If you pull an arquero date from a table, you get some object. `aq.op.UTCDate(mydate)` seems to just give the *day* not the *date*.

What is the method for getting the iso date? Yes, I can just manually assemble, but there must be a method hidden in the docs.

Want like standard `"2021-01-01"`.

Answer (score 0):

[`format_utcdate()`](https://uwdata.github.io/arquero/api/op.html#format_utcdate) is probably what you are looking for.

`op.format_utcdate(date, true)` will return a formatted string like `"2001-01-01"`.